# PHP session looks corrupt

Tags: php, session

This is used to get a list of previously served markers from session:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['markers'])) {
    $_SESSION['markers'] = array(0);
    $list = '0';
} else {
    $list = implode(', ', $_SESSION['markers']);
}
```

I use `$list` to get markers not already served:

```
SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE {other conditions} AND `marker_id` NOT IN($list)
```

Then for each row returned I add the marker id to session:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $_SESSION['markers'][] = (int) $row['marker_id'];
  ...
}
```

However, after serving some markers (say 8, 36) the session looks corrupt. `var_dump($_SESSION);` outputs:

```
array(1) {
  ["markers"]=>
  &array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(8)
    [2]=>
    int(36)
  }
}
```

I say it is corrupt because when I manually make a similar array ([codepad here](http://codepad.org/4ZxRo1IG)) the output does not show a `&` in the third line - it is `array(3)`, not `&array(3)`. What is causing this?

**Update**
@Marc B is hinting *the session is not corrupt*. His take is that we just have a variable ($_SESSION), containing a reference to an array ($markers), instead of the array itself; and *that is not a corrupt variable*. Well, the session *is* corrupt for *session usage purposes*. Two signs:

1. A second call to the same script (in which I guess the `else` route is taken) results in a `fatal error`: `Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array in  ... on line 47`. Line 47 is where we attempt to add a new marker id to the array: `$_SESSION['markers'][] = (int) $row['marker_id'];`
2. When I try to unserialize the actual contents of session file it fails ([codepad here](http://codepad.org/DxixDBqw)).

Comment: That's not "corrupt" - something's just turned that array into a reference to an array.

Comment: It looks like an array reference, though I do not know the answer why that happens, I may suggest trying using array_push in the while loop instead, e.g. array_push($_SESSION['markers'], (int) $row['marker_id']);

Comment: @Mark - all session touching code is what is shown above. Now, what in there is turning the array to a reference to it?

Comment: @Ruslan Kabalin - I cannot see how that could fix this, I will give it a try (out of desperation) though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have register_globals to On, global variables associated to $_SESSION variables are references. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: +1 Thanks! I checked register_globals and to my surprize it is `On` (shouldn't `Off` be the default for PHP 5.2.*?). I will check if turning that off will fix the issue.

Comment: Perfect! Turning register_globals fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting it from php manual 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Please note that if you have register_globals to On, global variables associated to $_SESSION variables are references, so this may lead to some weird situations.

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 42;
$test = 43;
echo $_SESSION['test'];

?>
```

Load the page, OK it displays 42, reload the page... it displays 43.

The solution is to do this after each time you do a session_start() :

```
<?php

if (ini_get('register_globals'))
{
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (isset($GLOBALS[$key]))
            unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
    }
}

?>
```